# photoshop paper roll/curl/folded effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I want create an animation, and for this I need to create some pictures. My example consist in a envelope opened. But I need to execute this steps:

[image: example]

1. Original picture.
2. Paper tearing(rip) effect - (This step it's easy and I know how to do).
3. Paper roll/curl effect.
4. Paper roll/curl effect a little more.

So, I need a help to do steps 3 and 4. I'm a begginer on photoshop, for my creations I usually search on internet for tutorials, but in this case I don't know what I need to search for.

Comment: Welcome to GE.SE!! A Google search for "Photoshop Curled Paper Tutorial" turns up over 500 tutorials. You're probably best starting with that then asking questions about specific problems you may have. Your question is a bit broad since no one will know how you envision "paper roll/curl effect" and in order to provide a step by step procedure, you're asking for someone to write a multi-page tutorial.

Comment: ok, but is this curl paper tutorials consists in fold paper from corners, and I need to do an effect like open and pull the paper

Comment: As I understand, you want some fast method/trick, not just manually editing your source material? Doing this the basic way, altho time consuming, is quite easy, varying slightly on what you aim for (style). In your example you pretty much did all the work. You would just need to fill the in-between frames :D

Comment: NICEEE Idea...i have urge to see it animate myself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is a great plugin called AV Bros. Page Curl 2.0

http://www.avbros.com/pagecurl/

Is not a free plugin, I tried the demo and it will save me a lot of time I will buy it.